# Automatically rebind controls on ASP.NET postback

Tags: asp.net

Is there a flag or property value I can set to have my controls re-bind on every page load, instead of just the initial one? I'm still very new to ASP.NET, so I would like to do it properly (if such a way exists) before resorting to the first thing that "works".

I am working on a simple WebForms page, which boils down to a few SQLDataSource-bound Repeaters; for example:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ExampleRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="ExampleDataSource"
              OnItemDataBound="ExampleRepeater_ItemDataBound">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="DataboundControlID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ExampleColumnName")%>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ExampleDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="example_connection_string"
        SelectCommand="ExampleStoredProcedure" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="exampleValue" Name="parameter1" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

After the user has interacted with my page, they can initiate a postback which will change the state of the database. I'd like the postback'ed page to reflect the changes to the database. Please let me know if I can clarify my situation any further.

Comment: How are you binding them in the first place?  (Also, are you using WebForms or MVC?)  Can you show us some code?

Comment: I've updated my question to hopefully clarify what I'm trying to do. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your processing i.e. updating database you can re-bind the Repeater by calling DataBind method like:

```
ExampleRepeater.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, some controls do, others don't. E.g. the standard ASP.NET controls from Microsoft always worked for me automatically, whereas the `ASPxGridView` from DevExpress needs a manual rebind on every postback/callback.